# Custom Experience Editor Ribbon Button: error in FieldEditor.aspx

Tags: experience-editor, ribbon

I'm trying to add a custom button to the ribbon in the Experience Editor (Sitecore 8.2). I've been following this blogpost: http://reyrahadian.com/2015/04/15/sitecore-8-adding-edit-meta-data-button-in-experience-editor/

When I Click my custom button, I get this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The base class includes the field 'warningText', but its type (Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Literal) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal).

Source Error: 


Line 135:    </div>
Line 136:    <div Visible="False" id="WarningRow" runat="server">
Line 137:      <sc:ThemedImage runat="server" Height="16" Width="16" style="vertical-align:middle; margin-right: 4px" Src="Applications/16x16/warning.png" /><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="warningText"></asp:Literal>
Line 138:    </div>
Line 139:    <div id="MainPanel" class="scFlexContent" onclick="javascript:scContent.onEditorClick(this, event);">

Source File: /sitecore/shell/applications/Content Manager/FieldEditor.aspx    Line: 137 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1088.0
```

Anyone an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Please include the Parser Error Message as text (for SEO).